# STM32F4-Discovery SPI

Tags: c, stm32, spi, stm32f4

I have to make SPI communication working on a STM32F4 Discovery board. I have configured it with CubeMX. The following code is generated to configure the SPI device:

```
hspi2.Instance = SPI2;
hspi2.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
hspi2.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
hspi2.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
hspi2.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
hspi2.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
hspi2.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
hspi2.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_4;
hspi2.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
hspi2.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
hspi2.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
hspi2.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
```

I created an array to send over SPI and send it using the HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA function.

```
uint8_t test[25] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,4,0,0,0, 0xED};
HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA(&hspi2, test, sizeof(test));
```

The problem is, I don't get the right output out of it. I connected a scope to it and I see only 16 bytes.

[Screenshot of the output from the scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P8uI.png)

This is the first time I work with a stm32f4. It's hard for me to figure out why it's not working. I searched on the internet and saw there were more problems with SPI on the STM32. I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Did you read the RM? Or maybe you believe in the "magic" HAL functions.

Comment: Before you eve touch any hardware abstraction library - learn oyur hardware. Try use registers first and learn how this peripheral works

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: I am sorry. My scope wasn't configured well. It works now.